# Difference between NOT IN and != ALL

Tags: mysql, sql

Does someone what is the difference between NOT IN and !=ALL.

Comment: What makes you want to ask this question?

Comment: I just asked that question to myself today but there is nothing on the internet which answers my question

Comment: Does you expand question to include context especially around `!= ALL`? An example would be good.

Comment: Well you clearly have some encounter with both function at some point and maybe you've tried using it but you still can't understand it.. maybe since each function return different results than what you expected. So, yeah, what danblack says - an example would be good

Comment: You probably want `NOT EXISTS` anyway...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems funny you are asking this question, since it literally says in the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/all-subqueries.html):

> *`NOT IN` is an alias for `<> ALL`. Thus, these two statements are the same:*
>
> *`SELECT s1 FROM t1 WHERE s1 <> ALL (SELECT s1 FROM t2);`*
>
> *`SELECT s1 FROM t1 WHERE s1 NOT IN (SELECT s1 FROM t2);`*

For readability I would choose `NOT IN`, but it's your choice.

Comment: Bad advice.  I would strongly recommend `NOT EXISTS` for a subquery, because it handles `NULL` values much more intuitively.